# Error while creating maven project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

When I create a new maven project from eclipse, I am getting the following error

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

This is the error I see in the `pom.xml`

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden

I am using:-

```
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 2.0.1.20130919-0803-Kepler
Maven version: apache-maven-3.2.1
```

I am inside company network, I have configured proxy settings in `settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the directory at http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 has been disabled. You can access the address in your browser and you will get an according message:

> Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
>
> View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.
>
> Find out more about The Central Repository.

To overcome this problem, you can pass a custom location for the archetype catalog file to maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml
```

Or you can download the [catalog file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml) and put it in your local `.m2` directory, I suppose.

If you are using Eclipse, go to **Preferences** -> **Maven** -> **Archetypes** and click on **Add Remote Catalog...**. Then enter `http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml` as **Catalog File**.

Comment: :Thanks for your answers, none of them worked for me. *"there are two versions (2.5 and 2.6) of plugin under
.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/
i removed 2.5 version then it worked for me"* - This worked for me